# I'm unable to login in admin and login is not working in Django project after Custom User

Tags: django, django-admin

**Tysm in advance, for helping** 
Already a superuser is made but admin login or login view is not working, Some problem in **authenticate** it every time returns none if **correct** password and email are passed
**Custom User Model**

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email Requierd!")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Username required!")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    userid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    #
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Already a superuser is made but admin login or login view is not working, Some problem in **authenticate** it every time returns none if password and email are passed!
[psql view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h19C.png)
**login view**

```
def login_view(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    if request.POST:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, authenticate
User = get_user_model()


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    #is_seller = forms.BooleanField

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password']

        def clean(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            if not authenticate(request, email=email, password=password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invlaid Login")
```

After login, it doesn't give me any errors and neither redirects to homepage!

[After login, it doesn't give me any errors and neither redirects to homepage!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufqNW.png)

**Tysm in advance, for helping**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set **is_active** field as `default=True`